# non-static JLabel cannot be referenced from static context while moving console println into GUI

Tags: java, static, jframe, jlabel, non-static

Whatever I try to modify there's always a problem and the program won't run.

The thing is that my program works fine, when it's launched in the console, everything is ok, but when I try to make a GUI, and get text from console in the window, variables doesn't seem to work as they were.

The program is very simple, it has three packages like this:

```
//class SklepZoologiczny in package sklepzoologiczny


package sklepzoologiczny;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import zwierzeta.*;
import magazyn.*;

public class SklepZoologiczny {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GUI GUI = new GUI();
        GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GUI.pack();
        GUI.setSize(300, 500);
        GUI.setVisible(true);
        GUI.setTitle("Appka Zaliczeniowa - Sklep Zoologiczny");
        GUI.setResizable(false);
        GUI.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

}

//class GUI in package sklepzoologiczny


package sklepzoologiczny;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import magazyn.*;
import zwierzeta.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public JLabel l_imie, l_gatunek, l_rasa;
    public  JButton b_dodaj, b_usun, b_lista;
    public  JTextField tf_imie, tf_gatunek, tf_rasa;
    public  String imie, gatunek, rasa;
    public  ArrayList lista_psow, lista_kotow;
    public  String pies, kot, gatunek_zwierza;
    public  String imie_psa, rasa_psa;
    public  String imie_kota, rasa_kota;

    public GUI() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        b_dodaj = new JButton("Uruchom Program");
        add(b_dodaj);

        l_imie = new JLabel("Text from console to GUI should go here");
        add(l_imie);

        event dodanie = new event();
        b_dodaj.addActionListener(dodanie);

    }

    public class event implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent dodanie) {



            magazyn magazyn1 = new magazyn();
            magazyn1.kasa = 0;     

            pies pies1 = new pies();
            kot kot1 = new kot();
            krolik krolik1 = new krolik();

            pies1.ustawImie("Max");
            kot1.ustawImie("Nuta"); 
            krolik1.ustawImie("Filip");

            pies1.ustawCene(200);
            kot1.ustawCene(100); 
            krolik1.ustawCene(50);

            pies1.ustawRase("Jamnik");
            kot1.ustawRase("Perski"); 
            krolik1.ustawRase("Mini_Lop");

            pies1.ustawGatunek("pies");
            kot1.ustawGatunek("kot"); 
            krolik1.ustawGatunek("krolik");

            System.out.println("Operacje Zakupu Zwierzat");
            System.out.println("---");

            magazyn1.dodajZwierza(pies1);
            magazyn1.dodajZwierza(kot1);
            magazyn1.dodajZwierza(krolik1);

            magazyn1.StanSklepu();

            System.out.println("Transkacje");
            System.out.println("---");

            magazyn1.sprzedajZwierza("Nuta");

            magazyn1.StanSklepu();

            }
        }

    }

//class magazyn in package magazyn


package magazyn;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import zwierzeta.*;

public class magazyn {

    public float kasa;
    ArrayList <zwierzeta> lista = new ArrayList(20);



      public void dodajZwierza(zwierzeta i){

            lista.add(i);
            sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_rasa.setText("Do sklepu dodano zwierza o imieniu: " + i.wezImie());

        }

        public void sprzedajZwierza(String i){

            for(int j=0; j<lista.size(); j++){

                if(lista.get(j).wezImie() == i){

                    kasa = kasa + lista.get(j).wezCene();
                    lista.remove(j);
                    System.out.println("Sprzedano: " + i);
                }

            }
        }

        public void StanSklepu(){
            System.out.println("Aktualny stan sklepu:");
            for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(lista.get(i).wezImie()+", " +lista.get(i).wezGatunek()+", " + lista.get(i).wezRase() + ", cena: " + lista.get(i).wezCene());
            }
            System.out.println("Stan kasy \t\t\t" + kasa);
        }
    }

//class zwierzeta in package zwierzeta


package zwierzeta;


public abstract class zwierzeta {
    String imie, gatunek, rasa;
    float cena;

  /*  public void checkProduct() throws ProductException{
        if(isDamaged == true){
            ProductException damaged = new ProductException();
            damaged.setErrorMessage("Product is damaged:");
            throw damaged;
        }
    }*/

    public void ustawImie(String i){
        imie = i;
    }

    public String wezImie(){
        return imie;
    }

    public void ustawGatunek(String i){
        gatunek = i;
    }  

    public String wezGatunek(){
        return gatunek;
    }

    public void ustawRase(String i){
        rasa = i;
    }  

    public String wezRase(){
        return rasa;
    }

    public void ustawCene(float i){
        cena = i;
    }  

    public float wezCene(){
        return cena;
    }

}
```

There are also three classes in package zwierzeta which only extends zwierzeta with no code in it.

So the thing is, whatever I try to put in the dodajZwierza in magazyn.java, there's always an error which says that I can't use non-static variable `l_rasa` to reference in a static context. I don't know how to fix this, I tried to make class as static in GUI but it just gets worse with more errors.

How can I get the text to appear in the window instead of a console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access non static variable defined in GUI class as:

```
public JLabel l_imie, l_gatunek, l_rasa;
```

Here:

```
sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_rasa.setText
```

I dont see its being initialised, but you could define it as static in GUI class like:

```
public static JLabel l_rasa;//initialize it may be and that would resolve your issue.
```

Comment: Thanks man you are the best, this works! Earlier I tried to add static into whole GUI and that's why it gave me an error.

But I have another question, there are supposed to be 3 lines of text, and this fix shows me only last line. How can I divide it into actual three lines? Can I somehow force JLabel to be longer than one line? Or maybe I can use another kind of label?

Comment: No so keep your other two label as is like `public JLabel l_imie, l_gatunek;` now use static version in another line as `public static JLabel l_rasa`

Comment: I did what you said, added two more lines like this:
    public void dodajZwierza(zwierzeta i){
        
        lista.add(i);
        sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_imie.setText(i.wezImie());
        sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_imie2.setText(i.wezImie());
        sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_imie3.setText(i.wezImie());
        
    }
also added labels, but after launch there are three times the same one animal listed, instead of three various from the table in the GUI. in console everything is ok. any ideas?

Comment: you are setting same text `i.wezImie()`

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. can you elaborate on what you mean?  I tried to add another methods like this in zwierzeta.java and paste in dodajZwierzeta      public void dodajZwierza(zwierzeta i){
        
        lista.add(i);
        sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_imie.setText(i.wezImie());
        sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_imie2.setText(i.wezImie2());
        sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_imie3.setText(i.wezImie3());
        
    }  but it always gives me just one animal.

Comment: See the method call  while setting the text `sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_imie.setText(i.wezImie()); sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_imie2.setText(i.wezImie()); sklepzoologiczny.GUI.l_imie3.setText(i.wezImie());` you are calling the same method `i.wezImie()` which will return same value and hence you see it as same value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you better avoid using members with names identical to type names:

```
GUI GUI = new GUI();
```

You - and the JVM - are more than likely to get confused by this, not knowing whether you are trying to access the class type or the class instance when you later run something like:

```
GUI.setVisible(true);
```

Second, if you want to let one class access a member of another class, it is much better to provide a getter that returns (a reference to ) that member, instead of defining the member as static and let the other classes access it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to conflate classes and instances: you want to create an instance of class GUI and then pass this instance around to be able to use the instance rather than the class.

In your main method, you create an instance of class GUI:

```
GUI GUI = new GUI();
```

The variable which refers to this instance you call GUI, the same as the class. *This is a very bad idea.* Java naming conventions dictate that variable names start with a non-capital letter, so you should write:

```
GUI gui = new GUI();
```

and change the rest of the main method accordingly.

Now, this *instance* `gui` is what you want to use. You have to pass it to the methods where you use it, and then write for example

```
gui.l_rasa.setText(...);
```

By the way, your code becomes more maintainable if you make the member variables of a class private, and add getter and setter methods to access them.